# "removeAttribute is not a function" error message

Tags: jquery, css, function

mac firefox 3.6.13 firebug gives me this error: "removeAttribute is not a function"
I have read somewhere that "removeAttribute" is buggy in some browsers however I need to use it. If it is a browser problem can anyone suggest a different method.

```
function closeThumbView(){
  $("#thumbReelBox").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $("#thumbReelList > li > a, #thumbReelList > li, #thumbReelNav, #thumbReelBox").removeAttribute('style');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use DOM element [removeAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) method:

```
function closeThumbView(){
  $("#thumbReelBox").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    els = $("#thumbReelList > li > a, #thumbReelList > li, #thumbReelNav, #thumbReelBox");
    for(ind=0;ind<els.length;ind++){
       els[ind].removeAttribute('style');
    }
  });
}
```

or if you want to use JQuery method, use [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) as one of the respondents said:

```
function closeThumbView(){
  $("#thumbReelBox").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    els = $("#thumbReelList > li > a, #thumbReelList > li, #thumbReelNav, #thumbReelBox");
    els.removeAttr('style');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 27):

removeAttribute is a JavaScript DOM function. Since you are using $(), and thus operating on a jQuery object, you need to use the jQuery equivalent, removeAttr()